# How can I make FluentAssertions ShouldBeEquivalentTo fail if expected has members that actual does not

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, fluent-assertions

I'm trying to make a "strict" compare using FluentAssertions ShouldBeEquivilantTo.  Everything seems to work good if the "actual value" has properties that the "expected value" does not but I need to achieve the behavior so that if the "expected value" has properties that the "actual value" does not I also need it to fail.  In other words I'm looking for all properties to exist in both objects or else I expect my test to fail.

Example: I want this to fail:

```
        var actual = new
        {
            a = "simple",
            b = new
            {
                c = "complex"
            }
        };

        var expected = new
        {
            a = "simple",
            b = new
            {
                c = "complex"
            },
            d = "missing"
        };

        actual.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expected);
```

Is there anyway to achieve this behavior? I have tried looking at an IMemberSelectionRule but it does not seem that ISubjectInfo nor IEquivalencyAssertionOptions contain information about the "expected value"

It's possible i'm missing something here so I apologize if this is a stupid question.

As an additional aside the reason I am comparing anonymous types is because these are responses from a WebApi controller in another assembly.  I  have exposed the anonymous types by adding my test suite as friendly using the [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("testsuite")] notation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't since it will only evaluate the properties that the `actual` has. This is something I'd like to change in [v5](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/FluentAssertions/issues/463).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  If I get a chance I'll take a look and see if I can come up with a pull request.

Comment: That would be awesome, but everything but trivial.